# AdMob mobile advertising - potential advertisers not mature

Tags: admob

I am looking at using AdMob as a revenue generation tool in my Android app. The difficulty I am facing is that potential advertisers will probably not be used to using mobile advertising, let alone AdMob. I don't think many of them advertise on mobile apps, only on websites. So there will be a gap for them to cross, I don't think they are willing to cross.

A solution could be to collect advertisements for them and then post them myself to AdMob.

Is this feasible, how can it be done and what are the pitfalls?

Please advise..

Answer (score 0):

Advertisers can use Google AdWords to create campaigns, and you can find more information: https://support.google.com/adwords#topic=3119071

If you want to these advertisers to run campaigns in your apps only, you can upload their ads into AdMob Campaigns: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6231370?hl=en, and collect the payment by yourself.

Comment: What if my potential advertisers are not AdWords or AdMob-savvy, they are not used to using it? Can I collect advertisements and post them for them?